# How to add reCAPTCHA in angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, recaptcha

How to Integrate reCAPTCHA in your Angular 2 Application?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried before, this is not a "we do that for you" site, we help you fixing errors that occur during your try.

Comment: I don't need an answer. I have posted the answer myself to share it with others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have Site Key and Client Secret given by reCAPTCHA. Put below code in component.

```
@ViewChild('captchaRef2') captchaRef2: ElementRef;
private _reCaptchaId: number;
private SITE_ID = [YourSiteKey];

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const grecaptcha = (window as any).grecaptcha;
    if (grecaptcha) {
      this._reCaptchaId = grecaptcha.render(this.captchaRef2.nativeElement, {
        'sitekey': this.SITE_ID,
        'callback': (resonse) => this.reCapchaSuccess(resonse),
        'expired-callback': () => this.reCapchaExpired()
      });
    }
}
```

Below is the Success callback function. If the response data has value then reCAPTCHA verified successfully.

```
reCapchaSuccess(data:any){
    if(data){
      alert("Congratulation! reCAPTCHA verified.")
      // Some logic goes here
    }
  }
```

Below function will be called when reCAPTCHA expired.

```
reCapchaExpired(){
    alert("Oops! reCAPTCHA expired.")
    // Some logic goes here
  }
```

Put below div in the HTML file.

```
<div #captchaRef2></div>
```

Put below JS script in index.html file.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer'></script>
```

Comment: With Angular 8 @ViewChild asks for 2 parameters. I've provided null as the second one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By putting above js script, sometimes I face below error:
"grecaptcha.render is not a function" 
so, in case you face this error just use following js script instead of above

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why overcomplicating that much if [ng-recaptcha](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha) exists?

1. `yarn add ng-recaptcha` or `npm i ng-recaptcha --save`
2. In one of your modules (such as `app.module.ts`, `shared.module.ts`, etc.)

(like explained [here](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha#configuring-the-component-globally-see-in-action))

```
import { RecaptchaModule, RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RecaptchaModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: { siteKey: '<YOUR_KEY>' } as RecaptchaSettings,
    },
  ],
}) export class MyModule { }
```

3. Use it in your `html` as `<re-captcha>`